Nginx Ingress Controller URL rewrite, but send original ingress URL in header
I'm using the Nginx Ingress Controller in a Kubernetes cluster, and I'm using the URL rewriting functionality.
My question is, can the controller be configured to add a header containing the original request URL?
I'm thinking of a scenario where the underlying service needs to redirect to an external authentication service, which, upon success, would redirect again to the original ingress URL ... but once the URL is rewritten, the underlying service doesn't know what the original ingress URL was.
I've seen some suggestions involving configuration-snippet, but this seems to have some pretty severe security implications.
I've tried using the x-forwarded-prefix annotation, and that helps the underlying service to re-assemble the original URL when the rewrite is a simple "remove prefix" operation, but that won't help if a more complex rewrite is required.

Try using the 'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet' annotation to add 'proxy_set_header X-Original-URI  $request_uri;' which includes the original  request URL in a header. This ensures the underlying  service can access the original URL even after a rewrite.
